# cloud drive vs. cloud files (or should we not bother?)

Tags: php, javascript, cloud, rackspace-cloud, jungledisk

The web application is in the process of moving from a standalone server to a pair of servers behind a load-balancer, and contains a 50GB directory of user-created data that is growing rapidly. On rackspace, the only way to add disk space dynamically is by also doubling RAM and monthly cost, which isn't necessary. So, to cloud files it is (unless anyone has another solution in mind?). Using JungleDisk, I can move the files to a cloud files container, and can mount the cloud container on both the servers, and create a symbolic link from the directories where the content was to the mounted drive. This would require no code modification. Alternatively, I could interface directly with cloud files using their PHP API, but this would require massive code changes (all the paths? really?). Is there any inherent problem with taking the easy way out in this case? I set up a model and it seems to work well, but I usually seem to be missing something.

Thanks,
Brandon

Comment: This question is probably better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: Arguably, but I'm talking about storage for a small web application, and it's not a very technical question. I suppose that many members of the community here have dealt with a similar problem. More, perhaps, than that of the server fault community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think mounting the drive makes a lot of sense for your scenario, but to be honest I haven't tried it with any load.  The good news is that you could always try the easy approach and then refactor if it doesn't perform under load.  I'd hope Rackspace accounted and tested for this exact scenario, it seems logical to me.

For some extraneous information, we faced the same question here and did a cost comparison of using Cloud Site vs Cloud Files.  We had to factor in both bandwidth and amount of storage into the costs because communication between Sites/Servers and Cloud Files still incurs bandwidth charges.  In other words, do you have a lot of files that sit around, or do you have a few files that get accessed often.

We spend a lot of time talking with RackSpace support about performance and scalability differences between Cloud Sites and Cloud Files - I'd recommend giving them a call.  We ultimately chose to just use Sites because of our needs, the cost difference was pretty insignificant as it scaled.  Also because the Cloud Files API didn't have the granular security that we needed, so we would have to have written a gateway service anyway.